# Else part of If Else not working in my Javascript Toggle button - ASP.net / Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, if-statement

Pretty new to javascript.

I've got a button, and I'd like to toggle its background color using if / else JS logic. My environment is ASP.net, c#, javascript, VS2013 express.

The 1st part of the statement works to change the button color to #198B07, however, the subsequent click does not seem to be firing the "else" property to set the color to "#2A303C".  The initial state of the button is to have the standard "gray" color.  Is that color getting "reset" on my second click, thus making the initial "if" true again?  That appears to be the behavior, once the color changes to #198B07, it stays that color for all subsequent clicks.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

**script**

```
<script>
    function myFunction2() {
        if (document.getElementById("test").style.background != '#198B07') {                
            document.getElementById("test").style.background = '#198B07';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("test").style.background = '#2A303C';
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" id="test" onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: `document.body.style.background` retrieves more attributes than just the backgroundcolor. But even if you were to use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` in my tests it returned the rgb values instead of the hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style.background` doesn't equate to a hex colour, it returns rgb values. To properly compare these you need to change the if statement to compare the rgb Ie

```
if (document.getElementById("test").style.background != 'rgb(25, 139, 7)')
```

This will change the background as required. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tybj4dbn/) as an example.

Comment: Works great, interesting that is can handle hex in the "do" part not in the "if" part.  Much appreciated.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery:

```
    function myFunction2() {
        if ($('#test').css('background-color') != '#198B07') {                
            $('#test').css('background-color', '#198B07');
        }
        else {
            $('#test').css('background-color', '#2A303C');
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a jquery / javascript noob.  I dropped this code between some script tags, and there appears to be nothing happening.

Comment: In this page you will find instructions: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HTMLElement.style.background returns a string representing the color in the RGB format. In your case, the value of 'document.getElementById("test").style.background' will be 'rgb(25, 139, 7)' after you set the exadecimal color '#198B07' for the element style property.

I suggest to not directly style the element via js, you could for example add or remove a class and style the element via CSS which would be a better and more mantainable solution.

Comment: Logic sounds good, but selecting the other answer since I can deploy it immediately.  Will make it a point to investigate your suggestion deeper when I can.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
   function myFunction2() {
        if (document.getElementById("test").style.background !== '#198B07') {                
            document.getElementById("test").style.background = '#198B07';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("test").style.background = '#2A303C';
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, getting same result.  1st click makes the button green (#198B07), but subsequent clicks keep it green.